# Spring Cloud Gateway redirection fails due to custom status 302 code overwritten with 200 status code

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

**Spring cloud Gateway version: 4.1.0**

I am trying to develop a global pre-filter that intercepts the incoming login request and use redirection to redirect to landing page if user is already logged-in.
For this I have developed a custom pre-filter that updates the response status code to custom status 302 (HttpStatus.FOUND) and location header with the landing page url as follows:

```
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
     // check if request is for login and user session is valid
     ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
     boolean updateStatus = response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FOUND);
     log.debug("Response status code update: {}", updateStatus);
     log.debug("Updated response status code: {}", response.getStatusCode());
     response.getHeaders().add(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, "<landingPageUrl> here");
     return response.setComplete();
}
```

After the successful boot up of the Spring Cloud Gateway application, I logged-in in the website and then tried to access the login page again.
But the browser is not performing redirection because the response status code returned to browser is 200 instead of 302. It seems the custom status code is getting overwritten somehow.
**Note:** The Location header is updated correctly and returned to the browser.

I tried to troubleshoot the issue and checked the logs and found following log files written by above code:

Response status code update: true
Updated response status code: 302 FOUND

I am now clueless about at which point the response status is getting overwritten in the request flow.

I also read about in-built RedirectTo gateway filter provided by Spring Cloud Gateway, however I need to update status code through code only.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/spring-cloud-gateway/gatewayfilter-factories/redirectto-factory.html

Even I browsed the code of RedirectTo Gateway filter and found it has also been implemented in similar code.
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/main/spring-cloud-gateway-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/filter/factory/RedirectToGatewayFilterFactory.java

PS: I have already gone through articles and none of them are working for me:
[Spring Cloud Gateway: Set response status code in custom predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69972629/spring-cloud-gateway-set-response-status-code-in-custom-predicate)
[Spring Cloud Gateway Change Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72901577/spring-cloud-gateway-change-response)

Please help in setting custom status 302 in response through code and return to browser to perform redirection.